# Linear regulator with high voltage and inductor circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor

[image: high voltage/current linear voltage regulator]

This circuit is based on inner circuit design LM317 IC. The circuit takes a voltage reference of 12 VDC and an input of 320 VDC, and should output 12 VDC, which it does, but in the simulation transistor T2 and the inductor keep increasing in current draw to 20+ A. The load is R3.

Note : The 320v was the output of rectifier and it was cleared out that the potential to ground is not 12v as it is AC the current direction changes and the potential is hundreds of volts.

The question is clear and it was answered, I added the answer but someone edited it and removed it.

The answer : the extra power needs to be dissipated somewhere that's why T2 was consuming high current, also inductor L1 is shorting the circuit and consuming high current.

Comment: Try calculating the power dissipation in T2

Comment: It was huge that what made me ask it didn't seem reasonable

Comment: Get rid of the inductor: it shorts the output.

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: It would be useful to know what are you trying to do. Is this just an exercise or are you planning to use that kind of circuit to transform 320Vdc into 12Vdc? In this latter case the approach is flawed for so many reasons. The main being the HUGE power dissipation that such a linear regulator would have to endure (as Kuba already pointed out). It's like put a forest on fire to cook an egg! Tell us the real problem you are trying to solve and we could give you better advice.

Comment: There is no LM317 anywhere on your schematic. The inductor is a DC short. T2 dissipates 1.5kW. The best R1 can do is make the thing not work. And even if you make it work, if anyone touches the output, they'll be badly hurt. This circuit is *not* powered from a "battery". It's powered from a mains-connected rectifier. By not including such details, you're fooling yourself. And please: do not attempt to assemble this circuit. No matter how you label things, all nodes are at unsafe voltages relative to ground. Whether you call them "12V" or "0V". Those labels are pure fantasy.

Comment: It was for a transformerless power supply and I wanted to know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I will do so, I didn't understand this point.

Comment: LM317 has an absolute maximum input-to-output voltage of 40V.  In your application it would instantly melt and blow up in your face.  Please do as @winny says

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0. You show an op-amp, not an LM317. So,let's forget about LM317 for now. Let's assume you got an LM741 there or something like that.
1. There is no compensation: the op-amp is unstable.
2. The load inductor is a short at DC, so you can't use it like you show. It's pointless.
3. The operating current is 5A. The circuit would dissipate \$(320-12)\cdot 5=1.5{\,\rm kW}\$ of power.

In other words: if you ever get it working, it will be a space heater, not a power supply. And good luck buying and paying for transistors that can dissipate that kind of power, and the heatsinks they would require.

I understand your predicament, but you are told that those ideas will not work for a good reason: they don't, and you don't have enough experience to not waste time trying stuff that anyone with more knowledge would know has no chance of working.

As for why galvanic isolation is important: The rectified AC mains, the 320V "battery" you show, has both ends at lethal potentials from ground. You can actually try this: Make a rectifier from 1N4007 diodes, connect a 600V 47nF capacitor to the "DC" output, then measure the AC voltage from each end of the capacitor to ground. Then do the same with DC to ground. Don't attempt to touch anything in that circuit - all points within it are at lethal voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffz3Zf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, let's look at four voltages. LIVE, + and - are measured relative to ground. V(+)-V(-) is the "battery" or DC voltage, that matches the 300V you wanted. Look closely:

[image]

As you see, **both ends of the DC voltage go up to 300V away from ground**. You touch either end, you'll get hurt.

Now you may ask: A-ha, what about if we use two phases and not just live and neutral? Sure, let's see:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5v5R7.png)</sup>

Ah, things are even worse now. Both sides of the DC output are lethal to touch unless you're very lucky. 400VDC hurts, and here there's no energy limiting. It's not a capacitor that will discharge. The diodes connect you directly to mains.

[image]

Now, are there ways to make such a power supply work and be safe? Yes. But the circuitry involved will be rather complex (an understatement), since you have to be regulating *two* voltages, relative to ground, and ensure that their difference stays exactly at 12V. And making it fail-safe would require extensive redundancy and testing. Like, you could pay a company hundreds of thousands of dollars to work on developing such an unisolated supply and not get something that any engineer working on it would consider safe to be touched. Even if it was exquisitely designed, it would still not pass any regulatory testing. Because there would be no isolation barrier, only active electronics sitting between the output and mains. And those can fail, and making the thing robust in case they fail is exceedingly hard. Not impossible, but **much harder than getting actual power supplies anywhere in the world**.

Given that you would want this supply to be used in a consumer setting, with thousands of pieces installed, this would have to be reliability better than petrochemical process plant functional safety systems, and those are insanely reliable compared to everything else.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful, but what gets me lost each time is where does the power go as the op-amp keeps turning on / off to stabilize voltage so it should be like a pwm right?

Comment: The op-amp doesn't do any such thing. It's a linear regulator. There's no PWM at all. Just because you stick an inductor into a circuit doesn't make it a PWM. The transistor T2 operates in linear mode, not as a saturated switch. And even if this was a PWM circuit, the inductor cannot be parallel with the load. Also: what will you power that op-amp with? It won't run off 320V DC. Also, this "supply" will kill someone. I hope you understand that the output voltage is 12V between two terminals, but it will be hundreds of volts to ground. If you touch the "12V" output, you die. Boom. Poof.

Comment: What about if I changed the supply from 320vdc to pwm at 10khz and 10% duty cycle, or can I use feedback from the op-amp to increase/decrease duty cycle with a 555 and a transistor

Comment: The whole idea of galvanic isolation is that you can touch the low voltage output without dying. It doesn't matter what tricks you use to make it work. The output will be lethal. Just because you and your boss think that there is a cheap solution, doesn't make it so. You are not qualified for this, your boss is not qualified, and you are wasting time while you should be developing good relations with customs people and figuring who to pay to get power supplies into the country. You're playing a pseudo-engineer while you should be working to solve the actual logistical problems you got.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot I thought the shock will be 12v, I would really appreciate if you could direct me to where I could understand more about how is it hundreds of volts to ground I thought it was 0

Comment: What about a choke, I don't know if it works?

Comment: And honestly I stopped thinking about making it for commercial use I just want to understand where is the issue with it

Comment: A choke doesn't isolate anything. And again: work on what you can actually figure out. You won't figure the design of a switching power supply from scratch. Your problem **is not a power supply**. Your problem is **not fixing the logistical issues you got that are fixable and I do know from experience that they are.**. Cheap 60W 12V switching power supplies are cheap as dirt, relatively speaking, and easy to get. The "problems" you have with importing them are self-imposed: you didn't want to work with the right people. And you'll kill someone, likely yourself, by playing with this stuff.

Comment: I'm an electronics engineering student I just do this job in summer, I want to learn about electronics as my knowledge is really limited although I was fascinated by it since 12 yrs ago. So I thought of this as chance to learn, but I really appreciate your help as I was going to build it and try it, I guess I will have to stay away from mains for some time until I know enough

Comment: I have another project that works on 180vdc to control a treadmill motor for ebike I thought this circuit might work as well, but how do I dispate power especially it will run on 20 A max, is this even a viable solution?

Comment: @AhmedH2O First off, you need to understand how to apply Ohm's law (surprisingly, many engineers coming out of school do not have a firm understanding of Ohm's law). You need to do research on linear power supplies first. Then, move on to switching supplies. There are AC-DC and DC-DC switching supplies, isolated and not isolated. Power factor correction is also part of the studies for AC-DC supplies. The subject is vast and complex - too much to cover in a forum such as this unless you have a very specific question.

Comment: Thanks @qrk i understood the issue and I need to understand electronics better first